# Apply a modifier with python

Tags: python, mesh, modifiers, shrinkwrap

I' ve written the following function to apply a shrinkwrap modifier

```
def shrinkwrap(obs):
for ob in obs:
    if not ob.type == 'MESH':
        continue
    msw = ob.modifiers.new("shrink", type = 'SHRINKWRAP')
    bpy.data.objects["body_2"].modifiers["shrink"].target = bpy.data.objects["body_1"]
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as = 'DATA')
```

I've problems with the last row (it is the function that should let me push the apply button shown in the following image )

[image]

In this image the target has not been selected, the function selects it correctly.

Comment: Hello, what exactly is your question ?

Comment: Yes, thank you :)